# how to set jump to method definition key binding in sublime 3 for tern-js

Tags: javascript, ide, sublimetext3, code-completion, tern

i've installed the [tern-js](http://emmet.io/blog/sublime-tern/) plugin for sublime 3, however for some reason I cannot make its command work with sublime's key bindings (I'm a sublime nube btw) according to the documentation.. `ternjs_jump_to_definition` is supposed to be a valid command.

So i put this in the default `(OSX).sublime-keymap` file:

```
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+j"], "command": "ternjs_jump_to_definition"},
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+r"], "command": "ternjs_reload"},
```

I also put this.. still didn't work:

```
{ "keys": ["super+ctrl+j"], "command": "ternjs_jump_to_definition", "context":
    [
            { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}
```

any idea what's going on wrong? I know that tern-js *is* installed.. because typing `Ctrl+Space` for code completion actually works:

any idea what I'm doing wrong? I simply want typing command+ctrl+j to jump to method definition.

Also I looked at the default sublime 3 jump to method definition (ie alt+command+down), and it only works on the same file even if i add libraries to the project. (I'm using [mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/), which works on top of [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is an old question!  I just ran into this myself (Sublime Text version 2.0.2), and I tried "ctrl+right" as my key binding.  It didn't work. My guess was because it was in the `Default/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file.  So, I searched for some key sequences to use, and discovered "ctrl+z" was available, and tried that.

The following is what I added to `User/Default (OSX).sublime-keymap` file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+z"], "command": "ternjs_jump_to_definition", "args": {"to": "line" } }
]
```

It only brought me to the top of the source file until I added the "args" parameter as shown. Now it takes me right to the function signature! The above is the **entire** contents of my User keymap settings, by the way.

I looked in my default keymap file, and I didn't find `super+ctrl+j` nor `super+ctrl+r` in the file, even with `super` and `ctrl` swapped, so I'm not sure what else I can suggest.